# Is there any way on Plesk to create two different git branches to deploy on two different websites?

Tags: git, git-branch, plesk

I just started with Git on Plesk, and run into a problem. I have created main branch and production branch. Each branch I need to deploy to different folders, for example main branch need to deploy to test.mydomain.com folder and production branch to deploy to [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com). Right now I can setup automatic deploy only for one branch.

Repository is on the Plesk.

Is that possible with Git on Plesk and how?

Comment: I'd recommend _not_ using git as a deployment strategy for different websites.

Comment: it is the same website, test is just online unlike local development, main branch is intermediate between local development and production development, since I'm not the only one working in local development